# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0627' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, python-2.x

I got the error in the title when I tried to save the data in csv file and I don't know how to fix.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
keys = sorted(self.Details.keys())     #### 1st sort the values of dictionary list
with open("test.csv", "wb") as outfile:    
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = "\t")
    writer.writerow(keys)
    writer.writerows(zip(*[self.Details[key] for key in keys]))
```

Comment: What’s the issue, exactly? The error message tells you exactly what’s wrong, have you tried anything or done any research?

Comment: Also, your code is unnecessarily complex. If your data is in a dictionary, just use a `csv.DictWriter`.

Comment: Python 2 was officially discontinued 8 days ago. I recommend you switch to Python 3, as the fix to this problem is a no-brainer in it.

Answer (score 1):

The default for `csv` when writing is ascii but your data has strings that are out of ascii, so if you are using python3, try:

```
with open("test.csv", "wb", encoding='utf-8')
```

If you are using python2, you can try this package `unicodecsv`: https://pypi.org/project/unicodecsv/

Comment: i really did but got this error which tell me encoding is not function argument
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: It sounds like you are using Python 2.  Please switch to Python 3 if you can--Python 2 is no longer supported as of the beginning of this year: https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: @OmarKamelMostafa `encoding` is an argument in python3. If you are in python2, you can use `unicodecsv`: https://pypi.org/project/unicodecsv/